# Slanted two-color divider between div sections

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to work out how to add a sort double-border slanted divider between divs (that may or may not have background gradient/background image so I don't think a traditional pseudo element with background color would work).

I've generated the below by creating a div with class 'slant' between the main two divs.

[image]

```
.slant {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: -32px;
}

.slant:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    background: linear-gradient(360deg, var(--soft-blue) 0%, var(--soft-blue) 50%, var(--light-pink) 50%, var(--light-pink) 100%);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform: skewY(2.5deg);
    margin-top: -24px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-background-clip: content-box;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

The div below has `clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 7%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);` which sort of lines up with the skew but this ends up misaligning as the div size changes or the screen size changes. I think I'm struggling with the difference between the degrees in skew and the percentage in clip-path. I'm also probably going about this in completely the wrong way! Any suggestions of how best to achieve this effect in a responsive way would be truly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make the whole thing using pseudo element, even the background part.

```css
.box {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset:0;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: skewY(5deg);
  background:
    /* the double border */
    linear-gradient(purple 50%,green 0) top/100% 20px no-repeat,
    /* the main background */
    linear-gradient(45deg,pink,lightblue);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```